# How to reRender an inputText generated dynamically by a dataTable using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-1.2

I'm using here in my project JSF 1.2 and the Tag `<a4j:support>` .

Well, i'm using here a `<h:dataTable />` to print on the screen a list of financial expenses, where it's possible for the user to insert new expenses or edit the existed expenses at anytime, the value of these expenses fields (amount, balance, value) are being shown in inputTexts components.

As i'm using a `<h:dataTable />` the inputTexts of it are generated automatically, so it creates dynamical inputTexts with dynamical ids. I took a look at the html source code of the page and the pattern JSF uses to generate the ids in a dynamically way is this:

```
id="formTemplate:tableForm:0:inputTextValue" ;
id="formTemplate:tableForm:1:inputTextValue" ;
id="formTemplate:tableForm:2:inputTextValue"
```

And in the xhtml page the code i used with the dataTable is this:

```
<h:inputText id="inputTextValue" value="#{item.value}" label="Value" styleClass="field" size="9" readonly="true" dir="RTL" style="font-size:12px;width:170px">
```

My business rule works like that: When the user types something in the inputTextBalance it calls the event onBlur where it automatically inserts an other value in the field "value", but to update this inputTextValue i need to do a reRender in my panel (panelDataTable), so it reRender the whole dataTable (dataTable is inside the Panel).

```
    <h:inputText id="inputTextBalance" value="#{item.balance}" dir="RTL">
      <f:convertNumber currencyCode="BRL" type="currency" />
        <a4j:support  event="onblur" reRender="panelDataTable" ajaxSingle="true" action="#{expenses.update}"/>                                                  
   </h:inputText>
```

**Now comes the trouble**, what i need to do is to reRender only the inputTextValue instead of the panel, but these fields are generated dynamically and i can't get there ids. Like i said before, this is the pattern that JSF uses to generate the id of the fields

```
id="formTemplate:tableForm:0:inputTextValue" ;
id="formTemplate:tableForm:1:inputTextValue" ;
id="formTemplate:tableForm:2:inputTextValue"
```

But when i use any of these ids in reRender attribute, the Ajax's log returns me this message:

```
18:23:57,208 WARN [AjaxContext] Target component for id formTemplate:tableForm:0:inputTextValue not found
```

I tried this but i got the same error message: `reRender="#{rich:clientId('inputTextValue')}"`

The weirdest thing here is that it shows me this message of the input not found, but in the html source code the id of he inputText is the same that i've puted to reRender.

Does anybody here have already delt with this problem? Any suggestions to me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should bind the `h:dataTable` to a variable in your bean, in order to reach the current row index.

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{myManagedBean.dataTable}" ...>
```

then you can change `a4j:support` like this:

```
<a4j:support reRender="formTemplate:tableForm:#{myManagedBean.dataTable.rowIndex}:inputTextValue" ... />
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the tip, but it didn't work, the id of the component is correct in the HTML page, but Ajax's log shows the same message error: 18:23:57,208 WARN [AjaxContext] Target component for id formTemplate:tableForm:0:inputTextValue not found

Comment: if "tableForm" the exact id of `h:dataTable`?

Comment: Yes <h:dataTable id="tableForm" styleClass="table" ... /> I guess this is a Ajax problem, it can't identify dynamic components. I mean, i did exactly what you said, the id of the components are correct in the HTML source code and Ajax can't find the component.

Comment: can you please add `prependId="false"` to your form, and try again with `reRender="tableForm:#{myManagedBean.dataTable.rowIndex}:inputTextValue"`?

Comment: Hello, i tried here prependId="false" .... But i'm still getting the same error above :(